# Yii2: How to filter multiple attributes using one filter attribute in DataFilter

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Need help on filtering multiple attributes using only one filter attribute.

```
     $filter = new ActiveDataFilter([
            'searchModel' => static::class,
            'attributeMap' => [
                'detail' => '{{classification}}.[[name]]',
                'detail' => '{{subclass}}.[[name]]',
                'detail' => ...,
            ],
        ]);
```

After doing `$filter->build()`, the filter condition only builds the filter for the last attribute which is the `{{subclass}}.[[name]]` attribute.

Comment: Your key name is same for all condition `detail`. Change it to different for each condition.

Comment: Can you point me to the right direction since right now  `detail` attribute is the only filter I need to fill up. Eg. `filter[like][detail]={keyword}`. I would like to know how to reassign `detail` on multiple filter attributes.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of using ActiveDataFilter, I went and changed my search process same to a normal search

```
    public $detail;
    public $classification;
    public $subclass;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['object_code', 'detail', 'classification', 'subclass'], 'string'],
        ];
    }

    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = $this->model::find();
        $query->joinWith([
            'classification as classification',
            'subclass as subclass',
            'group as group',
            'subgroup as subgroup',
        ]);

        $dataProvider =  new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params, '');

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'classification.name', $this->classification])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'subclass.name', $this->subclass])
            ->andFilterWhere([
                'or',
                ['like', 'classification.name', $this->detail],
                ['like', 'subclass.name', $this->detail],
                ['like', 'group.name', $this->detail],
                ['like', 'subgroup.name', $this->detail],
                ['like', 'subobject_details', $this->detail],
                ['like', 'object_details', $this->detail],
            ]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

I don't think this will be a good answer towards my initial question, but would like to post this as an alternative solution.